# Given a non planar graph, find a planar cycle basis

Tags: graph-theory

Having a nonplanar Graph, is there a theorem that tells me if I can always find a cycle basis that forms a planar graph or the opposite, that I cannot find it?

Can I add vertices in the nonplanar graph to find such a planar cycle basis?

So to say as an approximated (in terms of solution quality) valid planar cycle basis

Comment: In what way does a cycle basis form a graph at all - planar or otherwise?

Comment: The cycle basis forms a graph by starting with the initial nonplanar graph and removing all edges which do not occur in the cycle basis. The resulting graph is what I am interested in.

Answer (score 0):

The graph you're forming from the cycle basis is obtained from the original graph just by deleting edges that are not part of any cycle. This is exactly the bridges: edges whose removal disconnects the graph.

If deleting these would produce a planar graph, then the original graph must also have been planar. That's because we can put the bridges back, one at a time, without destroying planarity. Whenever we put back a bridge, we are joining two different components (which, by assumption, are planar). We can always turn the plane embeddings of those components "inside out" if necessary so that the endpoint of the bridge lies on the outside face; then, we can just draw the edge through the outside face of both components. This produces a plane embedding of the graph with the bridge.

Therefore you'll never get a planar graph this way if the original graph was not planar.

Comment: Isn't the cycle basis, a set of cycles that can generate all cycles in the initial graph?

Comment: Yes, and in particular its cycles must contain every edge from every cycle, or else it wouldn't be able to generate that cycle.

Comment: Let's say I consider the line graph of a complete connected Graph (of size N), therefore the line graph has K = N / 2 (N - 1) nodes. In this example I can always find a planar cycle basis of the line graph (with C = K - N + 1 elements), do you agree?

Comment: No, I don't. The line graph has $3\binom n3$ edges and $\binom n2$ vertices, so the number of cycles in the cycle basis is $3\binom n3 - \binom n2 + 1$, not $\binom n2 - n + 1$. That second one is the number of cycles in a cycle basis of the complete graph.

Comment: If you're hoping that every cycle in the line graph comes from a cycle in the complete graph, that's false. For example, if you take a sequence of edges around the same endpoint of the complete graph, that corresponds to a cycle in its line graph.

Comment: Oh, you are right. But I can say each cycle in the complete graph creates a cycle in the line graph. Now I can formulate even better what I want. I am searching for a cycle basis in the complete graph (C cycles),  whose cycles in the line graph (all edges which are not in that basis are removed from the line graph) form a planar graph. For complete connected graphs, I can find this basis, but it is hard for noncomplete ones. Do you understand my problem?

Comment: Okay, this makes sense.

Comment: Ok nice:) Do you have any hint?